# Nest 1.0 Elasticsearch, indexing DateTime as ISO 8601

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I'm using Nest 1.0 and elasticsearch 1.0. I'm indexing a POCO object, and I have defined a mapping:

```
_elasticsearchClient.Map<Customer>(c => c
    .Index("customers")
    .DynamicDateFormats(new[] { "dateOptionalTime", "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss Z||yyyy/MM/dd Z" })
    .DateDetection(true)
.NumericDetection(true)
    .AllField(a => a
        .Enabled()
        .IndexAnalyzer("nGram_analyzer")
        .SearchAnalyzer("whitespace_analyzer")
        .TermVector(TermVectorOption.with_positions_offsets))
    .Properties(props => props
        .Date(s => s
            .Name(p => p.Created).Format("dateOptionalTime").Store())));
```

But then when I check how that Date is being saved in my index, I get: 
created: /Date(1399890590)/

How could I fix that? I've checked the mapping being stored

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to fix. ElasticSearch stores [Date's as long's](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#date) by converting to the [Unix Epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) representation of the date. Your date of 1399890590 = Mon, 12 May 2014 10:29:50 GMT.